# "NullPointerException" when many references access my method

Tags: java

I have this class :

```
public class A {
     List l;
     public String method() {
         l = new ArrayList();
         try {
             .....
             l.add(new Integer(5));
             .....
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
             ......
         }
         finally {
             if(l!=null)
                 l=null;
         }
```

I have many users that run the same template (gtmpl) that contains :

```
A a = new A();
a.method();
```

The problem is in the case a user reaches `l.add(new Integer(5));`directly after another has  executes  `l=null;`. I get a `NullPointerException`. I don't understand why ?  I thought each thread will be assigned a list? What is wrong?

Comment: No. Threads will share the same list, l. Different _instances_ of A will have different lists.

Comment: Are you sure the NPE is coming from that particular line, not inside the `add` method?

Comment: @tbsalling can you explain that? I don't agree. If the new object is created in the thread as a local variable, it will be created once for each thread.

Comment: @Joe in the case it would be thread safe, but if the threads are sharing an instance the field is going to create problems.

Comment: The question explicitly states that each thread creates a new local variable `a` and instantiates `A()`. Have I misread the question?

Comment: @Joe - oh yes. You are right. Each thread does A a = new A(). Sorry!

Comment: That's ok! It's important to be precise in questions like this. It might be possible that the question isn't worded correctly, in which case it's time to edit the qestion.

Comment: @Joe : A a = new A(); and a.method(); are done in template. Many threads execute this template at the same time

Answer (score 2):

Do you create a new instance of `A` for each thread?  If the threads are sharing an instance of `A` then the field/instance variable of type `List` will make the code not thread safe.

One of the best ways to understand Thread Safety (IMO) is to consider the example Servlets in the J2EE environment provide.  Only one instance of a servlet is created for an application and the same instance of a servlet handles multiple requests (each linked to a thread), therefore if you put instance variables in a servlet your bound to have issues with thread safety.

Give [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2004/jw-0712-threadsafe.html) a read.

Comment: A a = new A(); and a.method(); are done in template. Many users run this template at the same time. So each user creates an instance of A and access the method. I think the normal behavior is that each thread creates List l. But the NullPointerException show that the list is shared. That's what I didn't understand

Answer (score 0):

1) If each thread creates a new instance of class A then, yes, you will have different lists.

2) If each thread uses the same instance of A, but each one makes calls to `method` then you will be reinitialising `l` each time with `l = new ArrayList();`

If you are doing (2) and don't want that behaviour then you could write `final List l;`, create it in a constructor, or write `final List l = new ArrayList()`. Doing this means that you'll get compile errors if you try to recreate `l` which will help with program stability; i.e. people maintaining your code in the future will not fall into the same trap.

Comment: A a = new A(); and a.method(); are done in template. Many threads execute this template at the same time. So each thread creates  an instance of A and access the method. I think the normal behavior is that each thread creates List l. But the NullPointerException show that the list is shared. That's what I didn't understand.

Comment: The list is not shared between threads if you are indeed creating instances of A separately in each thread. On thing to note: you are aware that the finally block will be called every time method is called, no? It's not the same as a (catch ...) as in C++. I think we need to see a bit more of the code.

Comment: Yes I know the difference between finally and catch block. I just want to mention that I mean by threads is that many users are running the template (gtmpl) at the same time